# Decomposition of polynomial $x^2 -3x +2\sqrt x$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Can someone tell me what's the rule/process for decomposing
$$x^2 -3x +2\sqrt x$$

into $$\sqrt x \left(\sqrt x - 1\right)^2\left(\sqrt x + 2\right) $$

Comment: Technically, there is no such thing as a “polynomial with a square root.”

Comment: You're right, I changed the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\sqrt{x}$ then $x^2-3x+2\sqrt x=y^4-3y^2+2y.$

Now just factor the polynomial $y^4-3y^2+2y.$

Comment: Got it, thanks!